# Improving Performance - Symbolic function applied to each row of numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, lambda, sympy

I have a list of input vectors that I need to use as inputs to a list of functions that are generated using SymPy. In the real application, the number of input vectors is ~100k, and there are ~5M sets of symbolic functions. This is currently the bottleneck in my code, so I'm trying to speed things up.

I've already made big improvements by using Sympy's lambdify to create lambda functions based on numpy, but I can't help but think there's a way to vectorize this and get the for loops into numpy/C instead of python.

I initially thought numpy.apply_along_axis() would help, but it still does the looping in python.

This is a simplified version of what I'm doing now:

```
import time
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

#Input for performance testing
# sampleSize = 200000
# inputVector = [1.2, -0.33]

# inputArray = np.array(inputVector*np.ones((sampleSize,1)))


#This array would have ~100k rows in actual data set
inputArray = [[-.333, -.558],
              [-.454, -.367],
              [-.568, -.678]]                    


start = time.time()


#These are the equations of motion of a mechanical system. Each row represents 
#a unique arrangement of components. There may be a better way to handle this, 
#but I haven't understood the system well enough to do so yet.

#This array would have ~5M rows in actual data set
symEqns = [['(R_1 - 1)/(R_0 - 1)', '0', '-R_1 + 1',     '(R_1 - 1)/(R_0*R_1 - 1)','1'],
           ['R_1/R_0',             '0', '-1/(R_0 - 1)', '(R_1 - 1)/(R_0 - 1)',    '1']]

for eqnSet in symEqns:
  #Create lambda functions 
  lambdaFuncs = []
  for eqn in eqnSet:
    func = sp.lambdify(['R_0', 'R_1'], eqn, 'numpy')

    #This is ~5x slower, due to use of pure python vs. numpy ??
    # func = lambda R_0, R_1: eval(eqn)  

    lambdaFuncs.append(func)

  #Evaluate each lambda func for each input set

  # in my actual code, this is a parameter of an object. forgot to store it in my example code
  outputList = []   
  for row in inputArray:
    results = []
    for func in lambdaFuncs:
      results.append(func(*row))
    outputList.append(results)

end = time.time()
print "\nTotal Time Elapsed: {:d}:{:0>5.2f}".format(int((end-start)/60), (end-start)%60)
```

If it helps, I could also structure the evaluation to calculate each function independently, creating a column of results for each function. Here's an example of the evaluation block in that case (using for loops for illustration, I'd like to get to vectorized evaluation using numpy):

```
  #Evaluate each lambda func for each input set
  outputList = []
  for func in lambdaFuncs:
    results = []
    for row in inputArray:
      results.append(func(*row))
    outputList.append(results)
```

[EDIT] For future reference, here's my improved working sample code for this problem. I've tweaked a few things from Oliver's response, mainly allowing for variable length input vectors:

```
import time
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

# This array would have ~100k rows in actual data set
input_array = np.array([[-.333, -.558],
              [-.454, -.367],
              [-.568, -.678]])



#This array would have ~5M rows in actual data set (generated via Sympy linear algebraic solns)
sym_eqns = [['(R_1 - 1)/(R_0 - 1)', '0', '-R_1 + 1',     '(R_1 - 1)/(R_0*R_1 - 1)','1'],
           ['R_1/R_0',             '0', '-1/(R_0 - 1)', '(R_1 - 1)/(R_0 - 1)',    '1']]

for eqn_set in sym_eqns:
  output_list = []
  for eqn in eqn_set:
    func = sp.lambdify(['R_0', 'R_1'], eqn, 'numpy')
    results = func(*[input_array[:,n] for n in range(input_array.shape[1])])  
    output_list.append(results)
```

Comment: It's better to add your improved version as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to make any concrete timings without the actual equations, but there are a few recommendations regarding your code.

First, let's talk about the equations:

- If there's always a column of zeros and ones, why bother evaluating?
- There seems to be symmetry in the equations: your `symEqns[0][0] == symEqns[1][3]`. Again, why evaluate?

What is the origin of these equations? I see that `R_1 - 1` is a rather common factor. Perhaps your original problem is much easier to solve.

Second, let's talk about the looping. You can get rid of one looping construct already, out of 4:

This:

```
for eqnSet in symEqns:
  lambdaFuncs = []
  for eqn in eqnSet:
    func = sp.lambdify(['R_0', 'R_1'], eqn, 'numpy')
    lambdaFuncs.append(func)

  # This seems out of place in your example code: whenever a
  # new row of functions is being processed, you lose all the 
  # data from outputList, because you're not storing it anywhere.
  outputList = [] 
  for row in inputArray:
    results = []
    for func in lambdaFuncs:
      results.append(func(*row))
    outputList.append(results)
```

could be changed into this:

```
outputlist = [] # Better position for outputList
for eqnSet in symEqns:
  for eqn in eqnSet:
    func = sp.lambdify(['R_0', 'R_1'], eqn, 'numpy')
    for row in inputArray:
        results = []
        results.append(func(*row))
    outputList.append(results)
```

Unless you actually need to store *all* the lambdified numpy functions, which I highly doubt.

You can get rid of yet another looping construct, by realizing your lambdified functions work exactly like numpy functions: they're vectorized as well.

```
>>> for row in inputArray:
...     print(f(*row)),
1.16879219805 0.940165061898 1.07015306122

>>> arr = np.array(inputArray)
>>> f(arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
array([ 1.1687922 ,  0.94016506,  1.07015306])
```

Same output, no for-loop.
That would bring your quadruple for-loop down to:

```
input_data = np.array(inputArray)
outputlist = [] # Better position for outputList
for eqnSet in symEqns:
    for eqn in eqnSet:
        func = sp.lambdify(['R_0', 'R_1'], eqn, 'numpy')
        outputList.append(func(input_data[:,0], input_data[:,1]))
```

This'll be much faster, because now basically you're only looping over the list of sympy functions, not any longer over the data (which is now contiguous, so has cache benefits) or the list of lambdified sympy functions. It would be very nice if you could add some timing results in the comments, once you've applied these techniques.

Also, a gentle hint: in the python programming language, most programmers follow the [PEP8 coding style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which means variables are all lowercase, with underscores separating words.

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough response. Short answer, this took calc times from ~ 18 seconds to ~ 2.8 seconds for a small sample case

Comment: I've updated my question with a few clarifications. 

Also, thanks for the nudge on coding style. I'm a self-taught hack that's been trying to get more in line with best practices, and this is a habit I haven't broken yet. I'll work on it :).